# Laravel Redirects to blank page after login submit

Tags: laravel, authentication, entrust

I have created a management system on Laravel which works fine on my local machine but when I uploaded it on my GoDaddy server the first page which is login works fine but after hitting the login button to verify it redirects me to the blank page

````
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
      "php": ">=7.2.5",
      "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
      "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
      "laravel/framework": "7.*",
      "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
      "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
      "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "~1.0",
      "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
  },
  "require-dev": {
      "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
      "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
      "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          "database/seeds",
          "database/factories"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
      }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Tests\\": "tests/"
      }
  },
  "extra": {
      "laravel": {
          "dont-discover": [
          ]
      }
  },
  "scripts": {
      "post-root-package-install": [
          "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
      ],
      "post-create-project-cmd": [
          "@php artisan key:generate"
      ],
      "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
          "@php artisan package:discover"
      ]
  },
  "config": {
      "preferred-install": "dist",
      "sort-packages": true,
      "optimize-autoloader": true
  }
}```

My site link: http://hrms.tafreehtv.com
````

Comment: I don't see any Laravel official auth package there. What did you use?

Comment: how you dont see it @Bulent "laravel/framework": "7.*"

Comment: First of all i would never recommend you to deploy laravel application on shared hosting. Use digital ocean for example. If you dont know how to setup everythin yourself they have service that will do everything for you. Or you can use any 3rd party deployment service as your wish.

Comment: Can you check on log file to see what error it has? log file path is /storage/logs/log-file-name.log

Comment: no error on the log file

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić laravel/framework is Laravel itself, not an official auth package. Theye are Breeze, Jetsream, Fortify. I don't know how someone don't know the difference.

Comment: @Bulent I appologise, i didnt even see word 'auth' in your first reply. I though that you are telling him that he is not using official laravel package. Btw i have none of them in my composer json and my app is working just fine.